# Input text with password pipe, ngModel anomaly

Tags: forms, templates, pipe, angular8

Try using the password pipe by combining it with an input "type = text".

I had the following problem:

First the code:

```
<input type = "text"

     (ngModelChange) = "user.password = $event"

     [ngModel] = "user.password | pipePassword">
```

The problem is that the variable client.password has the value returned by the pipe which are *********.

This line (ngModelChange) = "user.password = $ event" takes what is in the input box (asterisks that the pipe returns to me) but I need to take what the user enters.

regards

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

on html

```
<input type = "text"

     (ngModelChange) = "onModelChangeMethod($event)"

     [ngModel] = "user.password | pipePassword">
```

on controller

```
onModelChangeMethod(event: any) {
console.log(this.user.password) // your password 
console.log(event) // your event 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I need is that the pipe don't produce side effect over the user.password variable.